# Rails 3 nested routes with constraints

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I'd like to use UUIDs in place id standard IDs in routes.  This works:

```
# UUIDs are used for ids
UUID_regex = /([a-z0-9]){8}-([a-z0-9]){4}-([a-z0-9]){4}-([a-z0-9]){4}-([a-z0-9]){12}/
resources :posts, :only => [:index, :show, :create], :constraints => {:id => UUID_regex}
```

That is Rails accepts `/posts/fb0f7c67-6f9b-4e2c-a26b-7700bb9b334d` fine.

When I start nesting them like this, though,

```
# UUIDs are used for ids
UUID_regex = /([a-z0-9]){8}-([a-z0-9]){4}-([a-z0-9]){4}-([a-z0-9]){4}-([a-z0-9]){12}/
resources :posts, :only => [:index, :show, :create], :constraints => {:id => UUID_regex} do
  resources :comments, :only => [:create, :destroy], :constraints => {:id => UUID_regex}
end
```

Rails starts to complain: `No route matches [POST] "/post/fb0f7c67-6f9b-4e2c-a26b-7700bb9b334d/comments"`

What am I missing?

Thx in advance.

Notes: I'am on Rails 3.2.2 and ruby 1.9.3; `rake routes` is:

```
post_comments POST   /posts/:post_id/comments(.:format)     comments#create {:id=>/([a-z0-9]){8}-([a-z0-9]){4}-([a-z0-9]){4}-([a-z0-9]){4}-([a-z0-9]){12}/, :post_id=>/([a-z0-9]){8}-([a-z0-9]){4}-([a-z0-9]){4}-([a-z0-9]){4}-([a-z0-9]){12}/}
post_comment  DELETE /posts/:post_id/comments/:id(.:format) comments#destroy {:id=>/([a-z0-9]){8}-([a-z0-9]){4}-([a-z0-9]){4}-([a-z0-9]){4}-([a-z0-9]){12}/, :post_id=>/([a-z0-9]){8}-([a-z0-9]){4}-([a-z0-9]){4}-([a-z0-9]){4}-([a-z0-9]){12}/}
       posts  GET    /posts(.:format)                       posts#index {:id=>/([a-z0-9]){8}-([a-z0-9]){4}-([a-z0-9]){4}-([a-z0-9]){4}-([a-z0-9]){12}/}
              POST   /posts(.:format)                       posts#create {:id=>/([a-z0-9]){8}-([a-z0-9]){4}-([a-z0-9]){4}-([a-z0-9]){4}-([a-z0-9]){12}/}
        post  GET    /posts/:id(.:format)                   posts#show {:id=>/([a-z0-9]){8}-([a-z0-9]){4}-([a-z0-9]){4}-([a-z0-9]){4}-([a-z0-9]){12}/}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, when you set a constraint on a parent route, the child route will inherit the constraint on that field. Thus, my understanding is that:

```
UUID_regex = /([a-z0-9]){8}-([a-z0-9]){4}-([a-z0-9]){4}-([a-z0-9]){4}-([a-z0-9]){12}/
resources :posts, :only => [:index, :show, :create], :constraints => {:id => UUID_regex} do
  resources :comments, :only => [:create, :destroy]
end
```

is sufficient. Is this not the case? My apps are still in 3.1/1.9.2, so haven't tested in a 3.2 app.

Comment: Thanks, John, you are right, it works this way. My understanding was the same -- almost.  I believed that in case of nesting parent constraints are set for the parent ids (only): so that I thought your setup would take /posts/[proper-uuid]/comments/:id (for destroy, in my example), instead of the intended /posts/[proper-uuid]/comments/[proper-uuid] format.  It made sense to me but I was wrong.  I couldn't find any reference to the nested case in the docs, BTW.

Comment: Yeah, I've never seen that in the docs either, which is a shame. I only ran into it when someone else had the same problem and was experimenting.

Answer (score 1):

UUIDs use hexadecimal digits, so the a-z should be tightened to a-f. Also, hexadecimal is not case sensitive, so 'C' and 'c' are both valid digits. I use the following:

`UUID_regex = /[0-9a-fA-F]{8}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{12}/`

Comment: You are right, indeed.  (In my case I generate the UUIDs all lowercase and it is extremely unlikely that anybody would edit them.  Still your comment is perfectly valid and well taken.)

BTW: How about this one :)? ```UUID_regex = /[0-9a-fA-F]{8}(-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}){3}-[0-9a-fA-F]{12}/```

And to be more precise: my UUIDs are always class 4 ones so that can also be checked.  (I leave it to the reader, though. :))